# Excepción org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp

Tengo esta excepción en una aplicación que estoy trabajando en java web, sucede que dentro de la página que cargo, index.jsp, tengo hartos script de java y se que el error es porque no cargan esos script dado que para que funcionen tiene que iniciar sesión antes un usuario, pero esos script que uso me sirven para trabajar los permisos, por eso que no los puedo borrar. Si saco los script el código funciona, no digo que no funcione el index.jsp pero solo desde dentro, cuando un usuario inicia la sesión, el tema es que quiero solucionar esta excepción porque dentro de esta página tengo una condición para que redireccione al usuario al login.jsp con un mensaje de error, pero hasta el momento no se me ha ocurrido como se puede arreglar esto. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que uso para manipular el cod_tipo_usuario y hacer las validaciones más abajo según los números que le asigno según el perfil.

```
<%       
     HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
     //  int cod_usuario = (Integer)sesion.getAttribute("cod_usuario");
     String usuario = (String)sesion.getAttribute("usuario");
     String clave = (String)sesion.getAttribute("clave");
     String nombre_apellido = (String)sesion.getAttribute("nombre_apellido");    
     String perfil = (String)sesion.getAttribute("perfil");
     int cod_tipo_usuario = (Integer)sesion.getAttribute("cod_tipo_usuario");

     if (usuario != null && clave != null){
                %>`
```

Si saco ese código y los scriptlet que puse más abajo funciona bien si cargo el index.jsp desde el IDE y me funciona el error que puse en el login de que debe inciar la sesión, pero ese es el tema, que igual esos scriplet que puse más abajo igual los necesito ocupar para los permisos según el perfil que defino en la BD.

Comment: Ya revisaste los logs del servidor?, ahí viene cual de tus variables en tus scriptlets es nula.

Comment: Si, si se cual variable es la que me arroja error, es la que esta en este scriplet que uso para validar los permisos, es la del cod_tipo_usuario, esa variable uso, si borro esa variable y los script que puse más abajo vuelve a funcionar pero no es la idea. 
 <%       
                       HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();               
                    
                       int cod_tipo_usuario = (Integer)sesion.getAttribute("cod_tipo_usuario");
                     
                        if (usuario != null && clave != null){
                    %>

Comment: Igual probé hacer esto de otra forma, desde el servlet mandarlo a distintos index, pero el problema es que igual dentro de la aplicación, el usuario igual puede cargar los otros index, de los otros perfiles, entonces al final igual debo usar condiciones y cuando pongo condiciones en esas páginas vuelve a entrar a esta misma excepción y no me lleva al error que puse de que debe iniciar la sesión, eso es lo que aun no he logrado descifrar como arreglar esto, y hacerlo de la forma que estoy usando, porque al final igual necesito usar condiciones.

Comment: Es por que utilizas la primitiva int en vez de la clase Wrapper, en tu sesión todavía no existe "cod_tipo_usuario" cambia tu int por Integer y has la validación a null

Comment: Oh buenísimo, sos un genio, era cosa de cambiar el tipo de dato de int a integer y problema resuelto, gracias capo, ahora si al fin solucione esta excepción, gracias por la ayuda. Parece que el tipo int no funciona bien cuando uno usa la sesión, como que no lo pesca al parecer. Ahora me funciono bien la redirección al error que tenia puesto, eso era lo que me faltaba.

Comment: Pregunta solucionada, era cosa de cambiar el tipo de dato como se explica en los comentarios. Al parecer, el tipo de dato int, no funciona bien del todo. Gracias Ajeno por la ayuda!.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la primitiva por la Wrapper algo así:

```
Integer cod_usuario = (Integer)sesion.getAttribute("cod_usuario");
if(cod_usuario!=null) // pones tu sentencia a continuar.
```

Lo que pasa es que el tipo null no puede ser asignado a una primitiva, por ello era el NullPointerException.